# How can I calculate the mean and std using Polars in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writting a function called `industry_beta_f(raw_data:DataFrame, marginal_tax_rate:Expr)->DataFrame`. The following function takes two inputs: `raw_data` and `marginal_tax_rate`.

The function `industry_beta_f()` can be seen below:

```
pub fn industry_beta_f(raw_data:DataFrame, marginal_tax_rate:Expr) -> DataFrame{

    let df = raw_data.clone().lazy()
                                .with_columns([
                                    (col("Sum of Total Debt incl leases (in US $)") / col("Sum of Market Cap (in US $)")).alias("D/E Ratio")
                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    unlevered_beta_f_expr(
                                        col("Average of Beta"),
                                        col("Sum of Total Debt incl leases (in US $)") / col("Sum of Market Cap (in US $)"),
                                        marginal_tax_rate,
                                        col("Average of Effective Tax Rate"),
                                        lit(0.0)
                                    ).alias("Unlevered beta")
                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    (col("Sum of Cash") / col("Sum of Firm Value (in US $)")).alias("Cash/Firm value")
                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    (col("Unlevered beta") / (lit(1.0) - col("Cash/Firm value"))).alias("Unlevered beta corrected for cash")
                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    (col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")).mean().alias("moments_mean"),
                                    (col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")).std(10).alias("moments_std")
                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    when(col("moments_mean").gt(lit(0.0)))
                                    .then(col("moments_std") / col("moments_mean"))
                                    .otherwise(f64::NAN)
                                    .alias("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)")
                                ])
                                .select([col("Industry Name"),
                                        col("Number of firms"),
                                        col("Average of Beta"),
                                        col("D/E Ratio"),
                                        col("Average of Effective Tax Rate"),
                                        col("Unlevered beta"),
                                        col("Cash/Firm value"),
                                        col("Unlevered beta corrected for cash"),
                                        col("Average of HiL0 Risk Measure (Hi- lo)/ (Hi+Lo)"),
                                        col("Average of Standard deviation in stock price"),
                                        col("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)")])
                                .collect()
                                .unwrap();
    return df
}
```

I would like to calculate the mean and std for each row, across all the columns that start with `col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2"])`. I am having trouble since when I calculate the following as seen below I get that the column `col("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)` all the rows do not have the expected output.

The mistake is found when calculating the std. I was able to calculate the mean for each row, by doing the math instead of using the `mean()` formula. But I am sure there must be a better way. The error is that is calculating the Standard Deviation for the column and adding the result of each column, instead of each row. How could I calculate the std for each row, instead of each column?

Below, you can see the section of the code I am referring to.

```
.with_columns([
((col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")) / lit(10.0)).alias("moments_mean"),
(col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")).std(10).alias("moments_std")
])
.with_columns([                                
 when(col("moments_mean").gt(lit(0.0)))
.then(col("moments_std") / col("moments_mean"))
.otherwise(f64::NAN)
.alias("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)")])
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

**Current Output:**

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it inclueds a [mre] both *minimal* as in contains no extraneaus code and *reproducible* as in can be copy-pasted almost as is to produce the same error.

Comment: I believe just doing what the compiler suggests for `std` will work for both, when you minimized your example I'll try to check and write up an answer.

Comment: I did as the compiler suggested, and it compiles. But, when I am comparing the answer it seems that it takes all the values from the column instead of doing it by row. I described the problem better and added the expected output, as well as the current output.